# textbox auto newline when 50 character asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, textbox

I have a textbox for user to enter, the code below is how I create the textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtIncidentDesc" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="441px" Columns="4" Rows="8"></asp:TextBox>
```

I want like when user key-in a long text like

ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt

whenever it met 50 character it will auto new line like

ttttttttttttttttttttttttt

ttttttttttttttttttttttttt

does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance!

your comment and suggestion are much appreciated!

Comment: you can use onkeydown javascript fuction on texbox and check the length to split line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example. It will give you a clue and help you find a solution.

```js
    var cnt = 1;
    function newline(text) {
        var val = document.getElementById(text).value;

        var t;
        if (cnt > 1)
            t = (val.length / 10 * 10) / cnt;
        else
            t = val.length;

        if (t == 10) {
            document.getElementById(text).value = val + '\n';
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        }
    }
```

```html
<textarea id="tb" onkeypress="newline(this.id)" cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your textbox has word-break applied to it, perhaps in the CSS?

The best option would be to put a word-break: normal in your CSS.

Or you could do it inline:
`<asp:TextBox ID="txtIncidentDesc" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="441px" Columns="4" Rows="8" style="word-break:normal;"></asp:TextBox>`

Answer (score 0):

i was having similar problem,what i have tried is.

```
 <textarea id="txtdesc"></textarea>
```

Jquery code

```
      $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#txtdesc').keypress(function(e){
        var text = $(this).val();
        var lines = text.split('\n');
         if (e.keyCode == 13){
                return true;
            }
            else{
      //Should check for backspace/del/etc.

            var cane = $(this).get(0).selectionStart;

            var line = 0;
            var charCount = 0;
            $.each(lines, function(i,e){
                charCount += e.length;
                if (cane <= charCount){
                    line = i;
                    return false;
                }
                //\n count for 1 char;
                charCount += 1;
            });

            var currentline = lines[line];
            return currentline.length < 11;
            }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per you code you are not specified  any textmode so by default it will take textmode as single line. And about new line after some character, you have to check that and fire function to split. Here it was taking  the width as you mention then go to the nextline if we mention textmode as multiline.

So may this code help you to solve your problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function CheckReturns()
        {
            var txt = document.getElementById("TextBox1");
            var splitResults = txt.value.split("\n");
            if (splitResults[splitResults.length - 1].length < 50)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                txt.value = txt.value + "\n\r";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Call the script onkeydown of textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Height="50px" Width="500px" Rows="8" Columns="4" runat="server" onkeydown="return CheckReturns();" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```